# how to make a multiplication table in python

Tags: python, range

I'm learning python and I face this problem, i want to make a multiplication table like this

```
 1 2 3
 2 4 6
 3 6 9
```

I got this code:
    n = 4

```
rango = range(1,n)

for i in rango:
   for j in rango:
   print rango[j-1] * i,
```

but the output is this:

```
1 2 3 2 4 6 3 6 9
```

I'm making this script in python 2.7

P.S: Sorry for my english, english is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work to print a multiplication table

```
n=10
for a in range(1,n):
    val = ""
    for b in range(1,n):
        val = val + str(a*b) + " "
        print(val)
```

or modifying you way

```
rango = range(1,n)
for i in rango:
    for j in rango:
        print rango[j-1] * i,
    print
```

Edit: Apologies if my post is similar to another.  I was writing this as others were posted.

Comment: thank you! I tried adding print but not in that place, anyway thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just print a new line after each row:

```
for i in rango:
    for j in rango:
        print rango[j-1] * i,
    print
```

However I should point out that this would be clearer:

```
for i in rango:
    for j in rango:
        print j * i,
    print
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to add print "\n". Anyway thank you.